# How to start a line in plot from the end of the existing line?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to draw three dotted lines all of them at the end of the existing line. This is my dataset and code:

```
x = data.frame(Debt = c(115.413 , 116.522 , 123.361, 129.021, 131.786, 131.557, 131.397, 131.355, 132.1, 134.77))
future = data.frame(144.9, 147.9, 150.9)

plot(x$Debt, lwd = 2, lty = 1, type = "l", ylab = "", xlab ="", col = "red", xaxt = "n")
lines(????)
axis(1, at = seq(2010, 2020, 1), labels = seq(2010, 2020, 1))
abline(v = 2019, col = "black", ldy = 3)
legend("bottomright", col = c("black", "blue", "green"), bty = "n", lty = 1)
```

An example of the plot I would like to get is:

[image]

In my case the lines that I want to draw from *x$Debt* are the points in *future*.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can draw a line using the segment() function, e.g.  plot(NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), xlab="x", ylab="y")
segments(0, 0, 40, 40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not beautiful at all, but you can try this.
From your initial dataframes, `x` and `future`, create new dataframe combined two data, and slice the dataframe to show 
The code is as follow:

```
x <- data.frame(Debt = c(115.413 , 116.522 , 123.361, 129.021, 131.786, 131.557, 131.397, 131.355, 132.1, 134.77))
future <- data.frame(Debt=c(144.9, 147.9, 150.9))
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:(nrow(x)+nrow(future))), y= c(x$Debt, future$Debt))

plot(range(df[,1]), range(100,150), type='n')
lines(df[1:nrow(x),1], df[1:nrow(x),2], type='l', col='black')
lines(df[nrow(x):nrow(df),1], df[nrow(x):nrow(df),2], type='l', col='blue')
```

If you want to multiple lines in future range, you can append the data with years and values to the `df`, and add `lines()` with proper slices.